# Passing generic type to HashSet when doing collect

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Let's say that I have a map of company departments to a list of employee records at that department.

```
              Map<String, List<Employee>> departmentToEmployeesList = getMyMap();   

              Set<String> uniqueFirstNames = departmentToEmployeesList.
                    values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::addAll, HashSet::addAll)
                    .stream()
                    .map(employee -> ((Employee)employee).getFirstName())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The code above works, but I would prefer not to have that `((Employee)employee)` cast. Without the cast, the map call just thinks that each parameter is an `Object` rather than an `Employee`.

We can split this into two calls like so:

```
                HashSet<Employees> flattenedEmployees = departmentToEmployeesList.
                    values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::addAll, HashSet::addAll);

                Set<String> uniqueFirstNames = flattenedEmployees
                    .stream()
                    .map(Employee::getFirstName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now we don't have to cast and HashSet knows it's of type `Employee`.

Is there any way to pass type information to the `HashSet::new` in the `collect` call? Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Would be much easier and efficient with flatMap: `Set<String> uniqueFirstNames = departmentToEmployeesList.values().flatMap(List::stream).map(Employee::getFirstName).collect(toSet())`

Comment: But you can do HashSet<Employee>::new

Comment: Yikes - I missed that somehow! Feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HashSet<Employee>::new`.

But I'd rather refactor your code to use flatMap:

```
Set<String> uniqueFirstNames = 
    departmentToEmployeesList.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map‌​(Employee::getFirstN‌​ame)
        .collect(toSet()‌​);
```

Comment: I will refactor according to your suggestion. Makes more sense.